# Taking the partial derivative of the demand function

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, optimization

Define the demand function which maximizes x -> U(x) as:

$\sum_{i=1}^n$$p_i$$\zeta_i$(**p**, I) = I

According to my textbook if I differentiate this with respect to $p_j$ I will obtain,

$\zeta_j$(**p**, I) + $\sum_{i=1}^n$$p_i$$\frac{\partial \zeta_i}{\partial p_j}$(**p**,I) = 0

I don't understand how I get from the demand function to the output by differentiating w.r.t. $p_j$ do I have to use the chain rule, I tried that, I don't see why the function is equal to zero?

Thanks

Comment: Yeah all that is being done is the chain rule and, since the RHS does not contain $p_j$, it becomes zero. Although this is more of a math question and would likely be more appropriate on math.se as it does not really contain economics per se. If I were to answer this question formally it would have no economics, only a math explanation of how to get from A to B

Comment: The $i$ and $j$ subscripts are missing in $\zeta$ (3 occurrences)